# Cuadro de texto BOOTSTRAP 4.0

Tags: bootstrap-4

Trato de hacer un cuadro de dialogo como este en Bootstrap 4.0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Ideas?

Comment: Una muy buena idea es que revises la documentación de bootstrap, intentes hacerlo y regreses si tienes una duda puntual. Recuerda que la comunidad tiene reglas para elaborar preguntas de calidad. [Más info aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Y si en lugar de bootstrap usas css directamente???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo ajustaría o crearía un componente nuevo de Bootstrap así:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="textbox">
    <div class="textbox--border"></div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Completa tu FODA con MECA</li>
        <li>Realiza tu MECA</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.textbox {
  background-color: #1DACE4;
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.textbox:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  left: -30px;
  border: solid 15px transparent;
  border-right-color: #1DACE4;
  z-index: 1;
}
.textbox--border {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #8E8E8E;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: -6px;
  left: 6px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.textbox--border:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: -12px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-top: 2px solid #8E8E8E;
  border-left: 2px solid #8E8E8E;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: #1DACE4;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://codepen.io/spardo6/pen/KKQyQPj